# Localstack not creating cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

I´m trying to create a Cognito using localstack locally but when I run:

```
awslocal cognito-idp create-user-pool --pool-name test
```

as mentioned on the [docs](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/cognito/) I get the following error:

> 2022-11-01T19:21:56.136 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain:
> 2022-11-01T19:21:56.136  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.service     : API action 'CreateUserPool' for service 'cognito-idp' not yet implemented or pro feature - check https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/feature-coverage for further information
> 2022-11-01T19:21:56.137  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS cognito-idp.CreateUserPool => 501 (InternalFailure)

Anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented on the on the localstack [getting started](https://docs.localstack.cloud/get-started/) page, certain features are limited to paying members of Localstack Pro.

> The Pro version of LocalStack supports additional APIs and advanced features. You can find a comprehensive list of supported APIs on our ⭐ Feature Coverage page.

Following the [link](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/feature-coverage/) (which is the same link as in your error message you posted), Cognito is a paid feature of localstack. You have to pay for localstack Pro (or use the Pro trial) to get access to paid features.

> Cognito Identity Provider (IdP) (Pro)

There is a guide on how to get started with localstack pro [here](https://docs.localstack.cloud/get-started/pro/).